# Pull user details from UserModel in Keycloak

Tags: java, keycloak, openid-connect, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I have not implemented spring security with keycloak. So, SecurityContext is null. I can see that eventlisteners are able to pull the userID and userName. I am implementing a custom logging mechanism, where I am intercepting every httpServletRequest to pull the attributes of the httpRequest. However, I am not able to find a way to stamp the userID and userName to the attributes of every httpRequest. I can see that userModel holds all the uer Attributes. Is there a way to fetch the userID and UserName and add them to my logging mechanism ?

Comment: You've "not implemented spring security with keycloak". OK, but how is it implemented, then?

Comment: @ch4mp - when the login fails, event listener is still able to print userId and username as part of the event, "login_error", I am trying to get that userId & userName.

Comment: You don't answer to my question. We have absolutely no info about your security configuration. How exactly are we supposed to explain how your login machanism behaves?

Comment: @ch4mp - application acts as a oAuth2-client, with keycloak configured to act as auth-server.